# AWS Glacier. Querying Inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-glacier

To retrieve my Glacier vault inventory, The process I follow is to ask Fast Glacier to retrieve the inventory and leave it running in the background overnight connected to the internet. While this works, I wonder if there exists a client that I can close after asking to retrieve the inventory and then open it again, possibly the next day and after one or more power cycles to check the inventory.

The necessity to keep the client running prevents me form using the computer the way I want. Say I install something and need to restart my machine, I can't because then I would have to start the 8+ hour wait all over again. I am also not sure if this method is resilient to network downtime. I mean, if I lose internet for a few minutes just as the notification from AWS arrives, then do I not get it after connectivity is restored? Do I have to wait for another 8+ hours?

Also, how do you query your Glacier Inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a multipart download you may want to look into.  Its purpose is to recover from connection problems. To get your Glacier inventory, you have to submit a job for the inventory for a specific vault

Comment: I know that I have to submit a job to query inventory. The question is, can I close the client after submitting the job, reopen it the next day and still have it retrieve the results of the job (i.e. the inventory). If am okay with using any client that supports this kind of usage.

Comment: Well, if you are asking about the vault inventory only, then yes the client would be closed because Glacier has the job request and goes to work on it. When it is ready, it would be up to your client to use remember the job ID and request an inventory refresh.

Comment: If Fast Glacier was designed correctly it should store the job ID that survives being shut down. Upon restart, it would need to recall the job ID and use it to query Glacier to see if the job is complete, and then retrieve the fresh vault inventory